# Import source code of lineage os to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to import source code of Lineage OS to Android studio, for that I am executing below commands

```
source build/envsetup.sh
```

then I am executing below command

```
make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

After executing the above command, I am getting below error

```
/home/amit/android/lineage/out/s.../android/lineage/out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: /home/amit/android/lineage/out/soong/build.ninja
/home/amit/android/lineage/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l /home/amit/android/lineage/out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b /home/amit/android/lineage/out/soong -n /home/amit/android/lineage/out -d /home/amit/android/lineage/out/soong/build.ninja.d -o /home/amit/android/lineage/out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: vendor/lineage/build/soong/Android.bp:31:8: module "generated_kernel_includes": cmd: unknown variable \'$(KERNEL_MAKE_FLAGS)\'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:52:50 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (10 seconds) ####
```

Does anyone have an idea, how to resolve this issue, thanks

Comment: Did you google the error message?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but did not find any solution, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after following the [LOS instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/import-android-studio-howto.html) for using Android Studio.  I fixed it by lunching my lineage project:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch lineage_XYZ-eng
make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
```

"lineage_XYZ-eng" is defined in my vendorsetup.sh at the root of my LOS device tree.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Michel, will check it for sure